# Set width of element to width of sibling

Tags: html, css, width

I have a slightly unusual CSS challenge to overcome.

I have a two column layout, whereby the width of the left column is set by the width of a main image, and the right allowed to fill the remaining space. There is a container under the main image, which could have a natural width greater than the main image. However, I want this div to be the same width as the main image, and the overflow to be hidden. Here is my effort at attempting this:

```css
.outer {
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.contentOuter {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
}
.inner {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer left">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="contentOuter">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer right">
  <div class="inner">
    Hello world!
  </div>
</div>
```

But as you can see, `.contentOuter` stretches to the width of its contents, regardless of what I attempt.

One major caveat I have is that apart from `.content` having a fixed width, I don't want any other hard-coded widths in my CSS; everything should be completely fluid, and the dimensions of the columns determined by the dimensions of the `.image img`.

So, I am after something that *visually* looks like this, but without the hard-coded `max-width` on `.content`:

```css
.outer {
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.contentOuter {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  max-width: 350px; /* Hard-coded for demo purposes */
}
.inner {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer left">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="contentOuter">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer right">
  <div class="inner">
    Hello world!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like it's working to me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeywEo?editors=110

Comment: @CarolMcKay Sorry, that CodePen you have there is my demo of how I _want_ it to look, but I don't want the hard-coded `.max-width` on `.content`.

Comment: If you want to use JQuery https://jsfiddle.net/fkramb1a/1/

Comment: @NenadVracar I'm open to using JQuery as a last resort, put I'd rather find a pure CSS solution first before resorting to JavaScript.

Comment: I never did find a way to do this in pure CSS, so jQuery was the way to go in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to solve this would be to simply use some jQuery. It would only take two lines of code to achieve this.

```
var imgWidth = $('.image').width();
$('.content').width(imgWidth);
```

Answer (score 3):

One option, though that depends on further requirements you may have, it so simply add to the lower block:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

This takes it out of the flow, and the enclosing element will not take its width into account for sizing, only that of the image on top. The `overflow: hidden` will then hide whatever overflows.

The drawback is that the height of the enclosing element (or the position or subsequent elements) will not take into account the size of this element.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/rsz0hb1g/

Comment: Nice idea, but I unfortunately do have elements below, so in real life this obviously causes some overlapping issues.